# Custom SOCKS5 authentication in Java

Tags: java, authentication, socks

We have a SOCKS5 proxy which we are using to connect to a server. The vendor of the proxy has implemented a custom authentication protocol - the auth method is X'80' from rfc1928 which requires us to send a token in the initial phase of the binding along with some more data.

Is there any way I could extend the 'SocksSocketImpl' class to perform that custom handshake?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to make the default implementation support private authentications.  It only supports auth method X'02' (USERNAME/PASSWORD). See the [source code for the default implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/master/src/share/classes/java/net/SocksSocketImpl.java). For what you want, you would have to use your own SOCKS implementation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was able to write a socket class which connects to the SOCKS proxy, but I couldn't find a place where to plug it in the code.  `Socket.setSocketImplFactory()` seems to apply for all connections and I don't want to end up rewriting the whole stack.